# Mutating object properties within an array with Polymer

Tags: arrays, polymer

I not sure how to solve this issue. I am sure someone will know this very quickly.

I have an array of objects and modifying a property. I have a firebase listener 'child_changed'. When firebase is updated need to update the array. Here is the code below.

```js
     dbRefList.on('child_changed', function(snap) {
          
          var len = this.grocerylist.length;
          for(var i=len; i--;) {
   
            if(this.grocerylist[i].key === snap.key) {
              this.set(['grocerylist', i, 'selected'], snap.val().selected);
            }
          }
        
          this.notifyPath('grocerylist', this.grocerylist.slice());

        }.bind(this));
```

When the array is modified I want the template repeat-dom to trigger. I know this.set will not trigger array mutation sub properties but again I am not sure how to solve this. I done research and tried so many solutions.

I can force a render on the template dom-repeat but I would prefer the data binding way.

Answer (score 1):

So this code (just the `this.set` you have in there now) should cause the value of `grocerylist.i.selected` to update inside the `dom-repeat` (assuming it's bound in there so it's actually showing up).

What behavior are you seeing? Are you trying to filter or sort the list based on the `selected` value? In that case, you might need to add `observe="selected"` on the `dom-repeat`.

(Also—have you confirmed that the `child-changed` callback is being called with the `this` value you expect—the element—rather than `window` or something else?)

You should be able to force a refresh by doing `this.grocerylist = this.grocerylist.slice()` or `this.set('grocerylist', this.grocerylist.slice());` ... `notifyPath` doesn't work here because `notifyPath` doesn't change the value, it notifies the element about a prior change (the second argument is effectively ignored).

Comment: It does update this.grocerylist with the new selected value that i am setting maybe I can try the observe="selected". I tried this this.grocerylist = this.grocerylist.slice() doesn't work. Thanks for the observe="selected" tip

Comment: So if the new value is showing up, what's the problem? It would be helpful to see a bit more code (like your `dom-repeat` and any filter or sort methods).